# Org Babel generated graphics and GitHub display

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, images, github, graphics

I'd like to build `README.org` files with graphics that properly render on GitHub.

Currently I find that, for example, `emacs-jupyter` babel blocks render images locally via `file:./path/to/file.png`. GitHub doesn't render an image referenced this way.

I know I can export to HTML and display things that way, or via GitHub pages, but I'm trying to use the simplest rendering method.

Comment: Are you talking about how GitHub renders org files or markdown files?

Comment: Org preferred over Markdown, so that I can use Babel to generate figures.